# Import an AMD JS library in a TypeScript file

Tags: module, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm stuck with the right way to import an AMD JavaScript library (https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js) into a TypeScript file.

I found its - not up-to-date - type definition (https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Proto2TypeScript/commit/0889dccbf6048f116551a73e77d75dd83553cfe6), but actually I was not able to find a way to use it and have the library loaded by RequireJS.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="Scripts/bytebuffer" />
var ByteBuffer = require( 'Scripts/bytebuffer' );

import protocols = require( 'protocols' );

export class Pippo
{
    readPayload( payload: ArrayBuffer, ECType: string ): any
    {
        var ECStruct = new protocols.ECStruct( ECType );

        var bb = new ByteBuffer()
            .writeIString( "Hello world!" )
            .flip();
        console.log( bb.readIString() + " from bytebuffer.js" );
    }
}
```

The two modules *protocols* and *bytebuffer* are loaded correctly, but actually I cannot see members of instance *bb* in Visual Studio. If I put the line

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/bytebuffer/bytebuffer.d.ts" />
```

and comment
    //var ByteBuffer = require( 'Scripts/bytebuffer' );
of course I can see methods and properties of *bb*, but the module is not loaded at runtime.

Is there a way to have the *ByteBuffer.js* loaded by *RequireJS* with the possibility to see its members in VS?

Thanks

Comment: I'm working through this myself with the most recent release of Angular2.  I'm attempting to include a AMD-based javascript library (without npm) and I'm spending an unusual amount of time getting it to work. It's amazing how little information there is to do this correctly - everything seems like a hack and makes some assumptions around using SystemJS, etc.  I did find this page from Typescript but I'm still not there.  Maybe it will help you.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax for declaring the interface of external modules:

```
declare module 'amd/module/name' {
    // module definition, probably with:
    exports = thingToExport;
}
```

In your case it should probably be:

```
declare module 'Scripts/bytebuffer' {
    exports = ByteBuffer;
}
```

**Put this after the bytebuffer.d.ts file!!!** Also see "Writing .d.ts files" in the [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files).

In  my case the `/// <amd-dependency>` and `/// <reference>` stuff were also redundant - you may want to try it too, to simplify your code.